# problema con programa basico usando Flask

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

estoy ejecutando un codigo basico como este:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def saludo():
    return 'Mi primer programa Flask!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

escribo las siguientes lineas:

```
export FLASK_APP=hola-mundo-flask.py

flask run
```

y el resultado es esto:

> - Serving Flask app "hola-mundo-flask.py"  * Environment: production 
>     WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production
>     environment.    Use a production WSGI server instead.  * Debug mode:
>     off Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
>
> Error: Could not import "hola-mundo-flask".  no he encontrado solucion
>   a esto, alguien que me ayude a saber cual es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

lo primero que te recomiendo es que siempre formatees tu código. Como está es difícil de entender.

Lo segundo es que si estás en Windows, en ves de `export` debes usar `set` y por último, no es necesario que hagas `flask run` para correr el proyecto, puede ejecutar `python tu_script.py` sin más.

Saludos.